# Bizarre reference behavior in Tree implementation

Tags: python, reference, tree, pass-by-reference

I've been completely perplexed by a bug in a larger system. Consider this class (each node maintains a pointer to its parent and a list of its children):

```
class Node:
    children = []

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.contents = dict()
        self.parent = parent

        if parent is not None:
            print self.children
            print parent == self
            parent.children.append(self)
            print self.children
```

Running this:

```
foo1 = Node(None)
foo2 = Node(foo1)
```

Mysteriously returns this:

```
[]
False
[<__main__.Node instance at 0x10051f128>]
```

How does this make any sense whatsoever? Why is the second node's children not empty? Perhaps I'm missing a basic understanding of a concept related to how Python passes references around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've defined `children` as a class variable. It's shared by all members of the class. Move the declaration into `__init__` and change it to `self.children = []` and you'll get the result you expect.

Comment: Ah... Sigh. So obvious. Thanks!